# Is there minimally functionally complete set of 4 binary operators?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Wikipedia gives [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Minimal_functionally_complete_operator_sets) of minial sets for one, two or three elements and also mentions that there is no irreducible complete set with four elements of binary operators.

On the contrary, russian wikipedia [states](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D1.84.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.BA.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B9) that there is minimal set for four elements but i didn't manage to find anyone. Can you help?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [the paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1942-051-00/S0002-9947-1942-0005281-2/S0002-9947-1942-0005281-2.pdf) that the English Wikipedia article references. I don't see a reference for the Russian one, so it's a bit hard to follow up on the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Russian Wikipedia doesn't say **binary**. For binary functions, any non-monotonic function doesn't belong to at least two other Post sets, so there is indeed no irreducible complete set with four elements of binary operators.

Set $\{0,\, 1,\, xy,\, x \oplus y \oplus z\}$ is irreducible.